# Exact Target SOAP API - Failed to create subscriber: Invalid DPV: EXTERNAL_KEY

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using the Exact Target SOAP API to create a subscriber list and add subscribers to that list. To do this I'm following [this example](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_subscriber/).

The method below takes an array of subscribers (the Subscriber class is a subclass of APIObject) and calls the Create() API method to create the subscribers.

```
private void CreateSubscribers(APIObject[] subscribers)
{
    CreateOptions createOptions = new CreateOptions
    {
        SaveOptions = new[]
        {
            new SaveOption
            {
                SaveAction = SaveAction.UpdateAdd,
                PropertyName = "*"
            }
        }
    };

    string requestId;
    string status;

    CreateResult[] createResults = this.soapClient.Create(
        createOptions,
        subscribers,
        out requestId,
        out status);

    foreach (CreateResult result in createResults)
    {
        if (result.StatusCode != "OK")
        {
            string message = string.Format("Request ID: {0} --> Failed to create subscriber: {1}", requestId, result.StatusMessage);
            Logger.Error(message);
            throw new AppException(message);
        }
    }            
}
```

The method is being called like this:

```
APIObject[] subscribers = recommendationSets.Select(x => 
{        
    return new Subscriber
    {
        EmailAddress = x.User.Email,            
        SubscriberKey = x.User.Id.ToString(),                    
        Lists = new[] { subscriberList }
    };
})
.Cast<APIObject>()
.ToArray();

CreateSubscribers(subscribers);
```

The API call fails and I get the following error message:
    **Failed to create subscriber: Invalid DPV: EXTERNAL_KEY**

I've contacted Exact Target support and sent them the SOAP envelope that results from this API call. They've told me that the  tag is unnecessary for Subscribers and it should not be part of the XML in the SOAP envelope.

I don't have control over what exactly ends up in the SOAP envelope. I have tried both setting the CustomerKey property of each Subscriber object to null and not setting it at all. Both result in the same error message.

Removing the CustomerKey property altogether is not an option as it's a property of the APIObject base class and not a property of Subscriber.

Is there anything else I can try go get this working?

Comment: That error is related to profile attributes which are configured different for each account. Do you have a profile attribute in your account called EXTERNAL_KEY? If so, does that attribute have any constraints on it like a restricted list of values?  This can be found in the UI by going to Email > Subscribers > Profile Management